# Delete a file by rev or id

Tags: dropbox-api

I am uploading images to dropbox via the API call seen here:

```
        var promise_uploadDropbox = xhr('https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/Screenshot.png?overwrite=false', {
            aMethod: 'PUT',
            Headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + gEditor.dropboxOauth.access_token,
                'Content-Type': myBlob.type,
                'Content-Length': myBlob.size
            },
            aPostData: myBlob,
            aResponseType: 'json'
        });
```

I save in history the `response.path` for future, so I can delete this image, however if the user renames the image on the dropbox web app, then this delete operation will fail. Is there a way to find an image by a given `rev` or other identification, as this is supplied in the response object of the api call above.

### Backstory for this need

I have created a Firefox addon. In this addon users take a screenshot and then edit/crop it, then save it, after the save is complete I copy to the clipboard the file or http path to the image so they can use in forums in galleries, etc etc etc (aside: perm img link important). People like the option of cloud storage so I am brining Dropbox.

I keep a history of the users actions in a HTLM5 application, form this dashboard, I give users a quick way to copy image link, or delete from server the file. (aside: another point where a perm link to the image is important as its an offline app, and I show the image in the )`

Here is a image of my dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-preview/documentation/http#documentation) (currently in preview) has a concept of IDs for files, and you will indeed be able to delete by file ID in API v2.

But for API v1 (the current version), no such ID exists.

**EDIT**: I thought deleting by file ID already worked in API v2, but it turns out it doesn't! It will by v2 release, though.

Comment: Ah thanks Smarx, do you know when it will release because I'll set my addon next version up for v2 and release at same time.

Comment: Will the id be returned on upload of the file? I see it is marked a `optional` in the `/upload` so Im scared :(

Comment: We don't have a release date for API v2 yet. Yes, it will be returned on `/upload`.

Comment: Aw dang, but this id thing and delete thing looks pretty stable no? I know stable cant be guranteed but it sounds pretty stable. You think safe for no change like 90%? And if a change happens I can just update my addon. I want to just set it up for v2 right away :)

Comment: Keep in mind the `delete` method doesn't actually accept file IDs yet. (See my edit.)

Comment: Its out!! Thank you smarx!! :) The docs dont show how i can pass to /delete the id obtained from /upload though :(